# Rails 4 - nil value on rake db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4, and have created a `seed.rb` file with the values to add to my db.

Here's the db schema (Postgres DB):

```
create_table :teams do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.string :nickname
  t.string :icon
  t.text :description
  t.timestamps
end
```

Here's a seed row:

```
Team.create(id: 367, name: 'Wright State Raiders', icon: 'logos/Wright-State-Raiders.gif')
```

NOTE: I'm using `carrierwave` to handle the icons, but assume I can load them directly as well?

Here's the line from the `development.log`:

```
INSERT INTO "teams" ("created_at", "icon", "id", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["created_at", Tue, 20 May 2014 17:13:23 UTC +00:00], ["icon", nil], ["id", 367], ["name", "Wright State Raiders"], ["updated_at", Tue, 20 May 2014 17:13:23 UTC +00:00]]
```

Any idea why the `icon` value is `nil`? This happened on all 350+ rows.

EDIT: Adding more info that may be part of the issue.

The `Team` model:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :games
  mount_uploader :icon, IconUploader
end
```

The `Game` model:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
  mount_uploader :icon, IconUploader
end
```

The other tables involved:

```
create_table :teams_mid, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :team
  t.belongs_to :game
end

create_table :games do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.text :description
  t.string :icon
  t.timestamps
end
```

From `rails c`:

```
bundle :004 > Team.create(id: 400, name: 'Wright State Raidersll', icon: 'logos/Wright-State-Raiders.gif')
 (0.2ms)  BEGIN SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "teams" ("created_at", "icon", "id", "name", "updated_at")     VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 20 May 2014 19:07:30 UTC +00:00], ["icon", nil], ["id", 400], ["name", "Wright State Raidersll"], ["updated_at", Tue, 20 May 2014 19:07:30 UTC +00:00]]
 (2.1ms)  COMMIT => #<Team id: 400, name: "Wright State Raidersll", nickname: nil, icon: nil, description: nil, created_at: "2014-05-20 19:07:30", updated_at: "2014-05-20 19:07:30">
```

Comment: Why are you specifying what the ID should be?

Comment: @Jon-- because I need to be able to specify the key for another association. It just seemed simpler. Why? Is this affecting the load?

Comment: You shouldn't care what the ID is. On some databases, such as clustered MySQL, you cannot specify what it is supposed to be since the ID is dependent on which server within the cluster your request goes to. If you need to build associations, build the parent first then build the children off it. p = Parent.create; c = p.children.create ...

Comment: What is your database? Postgres, MySQL, other?

Comment: @tilthouse-- it's postgres

Comment: what happens if you move this line by 1 step?   `mount_uploader :icon, IconUploader` right after the Game class declaration? in Game model?

Comment: Have you tried executing that line (seed row) on `rails c`?

Comment: @Ako-- yes, results above